# Gmail Email id, dot(.) recognition

Tags: gmail

I keep on receiving email which is intend to be received by a gmail id similar to be mine, with no dots(.) in gmail id of other party.
For example : my email id is john.grisham@gmail.com
the inbox of above email ids, get emails intended to be received by  johngrisham@gmail.com

Question 1: The other party will also be receiving my emails ?
Question 2: How can i get rid of this problem?

Comment: This has been covered quite extensively here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178284/receiving-validation-mails-with-wrong-address and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138139/potential-exploitation-of-gmail-account-name-policies

Comment: Ultimately, this is not a security question (although you are concerned about your security) and has to do with how gmail parses addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Dots don't matter in GMail addresses.

Here's the [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en) for your further reading.

You can add as many dots as you like in your GMail address, and you'll still receive that e-mail.

It also says that nobody else can create a new, dotted version of your e-mail address, so there can't be "other party" you mention in your e-mail.

Since there's no "other party", I assume the e-mail you received was meant for you.

Comment: I created my gmail account in 2003, may be ignoring dot(.) from id was not present at that time and gmail was allowing to create different email ids with and without dot.

Comment: So is it error of GMail by allowing people by not ignoring dots while creating two email ids

Comment: I can provide evidence. Google should apply some excpetion in order to safe guard my information.